# SSRS & Parent-Child hierarchy & parent does not exists within it's own tree

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-grouping

I have an SSRS report that pulls data from a cube and shows expense items and cost values. Im using a parent-child hierarchy to show the expense items relationship and roll-up costs as well. I need to show a parent expense item within it's self to show the different between the roll-up cost and the actual cost incurred on the expense item. For example

Software Development 10000 (Parent)
 Software Development 2500 -- I need to show this.. (child)
 Unit Testing         2500 (child)
 UAT Testing          2500 (child)
 Deployment & Config  2500 (child)

Please help.....

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to edit the properties of the parent-child hierarchy? If so, then you can set the MembersWithData property to NonLeafDataVisible...

Here's a screenshot highlighting the difference between **NonLeafDataHidden** (left) and **NonLeafDataVisible** (right):

[image]

With **NonLeafDataHidden** (left), the values associated with the children for "Amy E. Alberts" don't add up to the subtotal $15.5mm...